# Access sibling variable of text-field

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple form, just a single text field containing a email from a MySQL database. The user has 2 buttons one can completely update the email with what they replace it with or they can choose to return the email to a default state i.e. the original email. It all works OK if you have the 2 buttons immediately 'in-situ' with the relevant text-field. But if you put the 'reset' button in a separate table cell, the 'onlick' set-email-back-to-default function stops working, and I don't understand how to fix it.

It will work like this because the reset button is slap-bang next to the text field:

```
<input name="cc_email"  type="text"  value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION["cc-email"]) ? $_SESSION["cc-email"] : $_SESSION['admin_username'];?>" />  
<input id="reset-cc" name="add" type="button" value="Set to default" />
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reset-cc').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('input[name="cc_email"]').val('<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username'] ?>');
        $('#update_cc').submit();

        return false;
    });
```

But if I place the reset button in a separate table cell as follows the function ceases to work as if it can no longer access the text field:

```
<td>    
  <input name="cc_email" type="text"  value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION["cc-email"]) ? $_SESSION["cc-email"] : $_SESSION['admin_username'];?>"   />  
</td>
<td>
  <input id="reset-cc" name="add" type="button" value="Set to default" />
</td>
```

I assume I need to modify the JavaScript so it can still access the text field even though it is now separated by a table-cell but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
$(this).siblings('input[name="cc_email"]')
```

By moving the input button into a different TD it is no longer a sibling (as the other answers have indicated).  You may want to just give the button an ID and reference it that way:

```
    //this bit |
    //         v
<input id="cc_email" name="cc_email" type="text"  value="<?php echo !empty($_SESSION["cc-email"]) ? $_SESSION["cc-email"] : $_SESSION['admin_username'];?>"   />
//...
$("#cc_email")...
```

Which will be easier than making convoluted parent/find calls.  This button *is* unique, is it not?

Comment: You're welcome!  IDs are usually the best option, when you've only got one of something.  The other selectors and methods are there for doing the more complicated things that can't be done with a straight ID or class.  No reason to use them unless you actually *need* to.  Otherwise you end up with a Rube Goldberg jQuery call.

Answer (score 0):

The `.siblings()` function searches in a collection of siblings within the same parent. If you put them into different parents then they are not siblings. Try replacing it with something like:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('input[name="cc_email"]').val('<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username'] ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input will always be in the same `tr` as the button, search for the input field within the row:

```js
$('#reset-cc').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="cc_email"]').val('original@example.com');
  $('#update_cc').submit();

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="cc_email" type="text" value="loaded@example.com" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="reset-cc" name="add" type="button" value="Set to default" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```